# Creating user profiles on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I was wondering if there was a way to create a profile for each user that signs up to my application on AWS. So for example: If you signed up to the application, a folder will be created under your username and will store your images etc, but this will be an automatic process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might have the wrong idea about AWS: It's not a set of solutions (e.g. user profiles) for you to choose from, but a set of tools with which you can program your own solutions.

That said, AWS has some things called profiles (e.g. IAM instance profiles), but that's not what you're looking for.

It sounds like what you want is a database with user records and an accompanying data store for images. For the former, you can choose from a range of Amazon services (RDS for SQL-based storage, SimpleDB/DynamoDB for NoSql). For the latter, S3 is your best bet.

But unfortunately, there will be no "automatic process", you will have to integrate those parts for yourself, in your application.